# How I can get related model for custom column in admin list_display with prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Hi I have two models with `m2m` link through third model:

```
class Group(UsefulAbstractModel):
    hotels = models.ManyToManyField(
        Hotel,
        through='HotelDetails',
        related_name='groups', )

class Hotel(UsefulAbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,)

class HotelDetails(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(
            Hotel,
            related_name='hotel_details', )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
            Group,
            related_name='hotel_details', )
    num = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(2),
            MinValueValidator(1), ], )
```

All groups has two hotel links with numbers 1 and 2. I need to display it in admin group interface.
I create two custom columns for each hotel:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def first_hotel(self, instance):
        return instance.hotel_details.filter(num=1).first().hotel

    def second_hotel(self, instance):
        return instance.hotel_details.filter(num=1).first().hotel
```

But for every instance I have 2 additional query now.
I tried to override `queryset` method, but in not helped:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    return super(GroupAdmin,self).queryset(request).prefetch_related('hotels')
```

Comment: Unless you're planning to add hotels with numbers 3, 4, and so on, it might be simpler to have two foreign keys `Group.hotel1` and `Group.hotel2` instead of the many-to-many field.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, it might be better and save me a lot of time. But this project is almost done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are filtering the prefetched results with `filter(num=1)`. This causes Django to do a new query.

You can use a `Prefetch` object to fetch the correct queryset. Note you should override the model admin's [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method, not `queryset`.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(GroupAdmin,self).get_queryset(request).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('hotel_details', queryset=HotelDetails.objects.filter(num=1).select_related('hotel'), to_attr='hotel_details_num1'),
    )
```

Then change your model admin methods to use the new queryset, for example:

```
def first_hotel(self, instance):
    return instance.hotel_details_num1.first().hotel
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for more into about `prefetch_related` and `Prefetch` objects.

Comment: Thank for answer, but I have error, because `instance` object has no atribute, which we define in `Prefetch` object

Comment: I can't tell why you are getting the `AttributeError`. As long as you use the queryset with the `Prefetch` object, you should be able to access `instance.hotel_details_num1`.

Comment: I found solution. I used method `get_queryset` instead of `queryset`, then
I change `select_related` query, because `Prefetch` object return list, not queryset, so I put it directly in `queryset` atribute, like so: `queryset=HotelDetails.objects.filter(num=1).select_related()` I don't understand why `queryset` method doesn't worked, because I use 1.8 version. Thank for help, update your answer please

Comment: Good job figuring out the bugs, I've fixed the code my answer. The method should be `get_queryset`, as shown [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) - the only place in those docs with a `queryset` method is for `SimpleListFilter`, which is a different class.